# $G_\delta$ sets in locally countable spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a locally countable Hausdorff space. I want to show that countable and cocountable sets are both $G_\delta$ sets.

The cocountable sets are easy as, if $S$ is cocountable, $S^c = \{x_i : i<\omega\}$. Then we see $S = \bigcap \{x_i\}^c$.

I am having difficulties seeing the other one. Let $S$ be countable. I do not believe we can use the same complement trick as we are not guaranteed the complement of a countable set to be countable. Moreover, I've attempted to take countable neighborhoods of each $x\in S$ and use that in our intersection, but I'm unsure if we can make these neighborhoods big enough to contain all of $S$. Any hints?

For reference, this comes as a remark in Roitman's article on Ostaszewski spaces in The Handbook of Set Theoretic Topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be a countable subset of a locally countable T1 space $X$. For each $x \in S$ choose a countable, open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$.
Then $F := X \setminus \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x$ is closed and $\bigcup_{x \in S} U_x \setminus S$ is countable. Hence, by T1, $X \setminus S = F \cup \bigcup_{x \in S} U_x \setminus S$ is $F_\sigma$, hence $S$ is $G_\delta$.